# Refresh image in command line (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, graphics, refresh

I want to make a game (something like [theses](http://www.the-tech-tutorial.com/top-10-command-line-linux-games/)) in C++ (Visual C++). Now a graphic game needs to refresh its picture quite often.

I can print around 20 blank lines. This method is unefficient and quite "laggy". What I need is something fast and efficient and that cause no memory problem because the game will process a lot of data (like mouvements, scores, coins...).

I've also tried to use `system('cls')`. This is quite bad because can "kinda" gives the player an *epileptic attack*!

Is there a better solution??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line has no image output. The only way you can fake it on the command line is the way you have described it.

The way to make a game efficient is to create a window yourself and then draw with DirectX or OpenGL something into that window. Then you can clear it and redraw it. This might not satisfy you at the moment, as it sounds more like a quick project. But in the long run, you will not be happy to "draw" on the command line if you search for efficiency.

Comment: Can I use Visual C++ to program it or is it an other software I need to use to write my code??

Comment: You can use Visual C++. The problem with OpenGL and DX is that they need a lot of initialization code and proper setup to work. I further refer to this tutorial for OpenGL: [OpenGL Beginner Tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/) Not just the window setup requires a lot of code, but also getting something to be drawn on screen requires knowledge of shaders - making a start quite difficult, unfortunatly! As you may see from the article, it will take you a while to switch :-/